# Is it possible to implement has_many, :through with ActiveScaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, activescaffold

Consider the following models:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artist_events
  has_many :events, :through => :artist_events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artist_events
  has_many :artists, :through => :artist_events, :order => 'artist_events.position'
end

class ArtistEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :order => 'position'
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :event
  acts_as_list :scope => :artist
end
```

Is is possible to use ActiveScaffold to administer this type of relationship?  The ArtistEvent model exists to define a hbtm relationship with additional attribute of position.

Thanks!

Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes. after all, ArtistEvent is yet another model - and active scaffold can operate on it as long as you have routes and controllers on the join model.